# Modificar consulta SQL para obtener resultados esperados

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Transfondo**

Estoy generando una serie de reportes a partir de información contenida en una base de datos en SQL Server.

Para efectos de la pregunta, llamaré a esta base de datos: **Prueba**.

De la base de datos **Prueba** obtengo la hora en la que ciertos usuarios han usado un dispositivo *Ejemplo: **PC***.

Los valores de fecha están en formato UNIX time y que, gracias a esta [**respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707629/4092887) pude adaptar en esta pregunta para mejorar la comprensión de los datos.

---

**Inconveniente**

Al ejecutar la siguiente consulta que tiene como rango de fecha:

> **05/09/2016 00:00:00 - 05/09/2016 23:59:59**

```
-- Variables globales.
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '1970-01-01' -- epoch start

SELECT ID, 
       (CASE Lector
        WHEN 539560940 THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, Fecha, @dt),'HH:mm')
        ELSE '0' END) AS 'Hora entrada',
       (CASE Lector
        WHEN 539560944 THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, Fecha, @dt),'HH:mm')
        ELSE '0' END) AS 'Hora salida',        
       (CASE Lector
        WHEN 539560940 THEN 'Entrada'
        WHEN 539560944 THEN 'Salida'
        ELSE '0' END) AS Lector,
       Evento,
       UsuarioID
FROM LogEventos
WHERE UsuarioID = 52698067
AND Fecha >= 1473033600 AND Fecha <= 1473119999
AND Evento = 55
ORDER BY Fecha
```

Obtengo las columnas **Hora entrada** y **Hora salida** en líneas diferentes:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   Hora de entrada     |   Hora de salida  |
---------------------------------------------
|       07:54           |          0        |
---------------------------------------------
|         0             |       09:01       |
---------------------------------------------
|       09:04           |          0        |
---------------------------------------------
|         0             |       10:21       |
---------------------------------------------
|       10:25           |          0        |
---------------------------------------------
|          0            |       12:27       |
---------------------------------------------
|       15:00           |          0        |
---------------------------------------------
|          0            |       16:28       |
---------------------------------------------
|       16:33           |          0        |
---------------------------------------------
|          0            |       18:51       |
---------------------------------------------
```

*Pulsa sobre la imagen para ampliarla*
[image: Resultados consulta 1]

Cuando lo que deseo obtener son los siguientes resultados:

```
---------------------------------------------
|   Hora de entrada     |   Hora de salida  |
---------------------------------------------
|       07:54           |       09:01       |
---------------------------------------------
|       09:04           |       10:21       |
---------------------------------------------
|       10:25           |       12:27       |
---------------------------------------------
|       15:00           |       16:28       |
---------------------------------------------
|       16:33           |       18:51       |
---------------------------------------------
```

**¿Cómo puedo modificar la consulta para obtener los valores esperados?**

---

He generado en el siguiente [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb0083) una estructura con datos de muestra, los cuales corresponden a la base de datos.

Comment: Cómo sabes cuál registro de entrada debe unirse con cuál registro de salida?. También, para el resultado que quieres, no puedes tener también la columna que indique que es "entrada" o "salida"

Comment: @Lamak, el registro de entrada está unido con el registro de salida ya que la consulta está ordenada por fecha; sé que corresponden a "Entrada" y "Salida"  porque estos datos los estoy comparando con un excel que _según el cliente_ es la información correcta. Las columnas de "Entrada" y "Salida" no son relevantes, la puse en la pregunta, pero puedo quitar la imagen. Solo me interesan las columnas "Hora entrada" y "Hora salida".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lo que necesitas hacer es un `JOIN` entre el subset de filas que representan las entradas, con el subset de filas que representan las salidas. Además, debes tener una columna que identifique el orden cronológico de cada una de estas filas para poder hacer el `JOIN` (esto según tu comentario, lo ideal sería que hubiera una forma directa de relacionar las entradas con las salidas).

Puedes probar este código:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '19700101';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UsuarioID, Evento
                                   ORDER BY Fecha)
    FROM LogEventos
)
SELECT  Ent.ID,
        FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, Ent.Fecha, @dt),'HH:mm') [Hora entrada],
        FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, Sal.Fecha, @dt),'HH:mm') [Hora salida],
        Ent.Evento,
        Ent.UsuarioID

FROM (  SELECT *
        FROM CTE
        WHERE Lector = 539560940) Ent
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM CTE
            WHERE Lector = 539560944) Sal
    ON Ent.UsuarioID = Sal.UsuarioID
    AND Ent.Evento = Sal.Evento
    AND Ent.RN = Sal.RN - 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Resuelvelo con un join, separa las consultas para obtener hora de entrada y hora de salida.

Debería ser muy sencillo, ya tienes los datos.

Comment: Por favor elabora mejor tu respuesta.